# What does it mean if an error message says a variable is referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def Q7():
    names=['ben','thor','zoe','kate'] #the list of names 
    Max = 4
    found=False
    Splayer = input("What plaer are you looking for? ")
    while found == False and current <= Max:
        if names[current]== Splayer:
            found = true
        else:
            current = current+1
        if found == True:
            print('yes, they have a top')
        else:
            print('no,they do not have a top score')
```

this is a programme asked me to do the following: find the player name and print out one of the output based on the user input however when i run it comes up with while found == False and current <= Max:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current' referenced before assignment
how do i get it to work properly

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: We do not understand... Explain... Explain Doctor... Explain... Exterminate the Doctor.

Comment: what is the question

Comment: Define `current=0` before the loop. That's just error reading ...

Answer (score 2):

```
def Q7():
    names=['ben','thor','zoe','kate'] #the list of names 
    Max = 4
    found=False
    Splayer = input("What plaer are you looking for? ")
    current = 0;
    while found == False and current < Max:
        if names[current]== Splayer:
            found = True
        current = current+1
    if found == True:
        print('yes, they have a top')
    else:
        print('no,they do not have a top score')
```

1. The checks for found are done after you are finished searching, and not done inside
2. declare `current` as 0.
3. loop from current -> 0 to Max-1
4. found is `True` not `true`

Comment: ... or just do `found = Splayer in names`. Also, `== True` is not necessary.

Comment: ya surely, just trying to help with the current code. @tobias_k

Answer (score 0):

```
def Q7():
    names=['ben','thor','zoe','kate'] #the list of names 
    Max = 4
    found=False
    current = 0
    Splayer = input("What plaer are you looking for? ")
    while found == False and current <= Max-1:
        if names[current]== Splayer:
            found = True
        else:
            current = current+1
        if found == True:
            print('yes, they have a top')
        else:
            print('no,they do not have a top score')
```

Comment: Actually, this won't work. `names[4]` doesn't exists. you need to loop while `current < Max`

Answer (score 0):

tobias_k is right. What you really want is:

```
names = ['ben', 'thor', 'zoe', 'kate']
player = input("What player are you looking for? ")
if player in names:
    print("Yes, they have a top score.")
else:
    print("No, they don't.")
```